# Distribution of primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Do primes become more or less frequent as you go further out on the number line?  That is, are there more or fewer primes between $1$ and $1{,}000{,}000$ than between $1{,}000{,}000$ and $2{,}000{,}000$?

A proof or pointer to a proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes (as has been answered): the heuristic reason is that we can list the primes $p_1, p_2, \dots$. Each time you apply the sieve of Eratosnese you exclude the numbers divisible by $p_n$ and weed out "$(1-1/p_n)$" of the natural numbers (i.e., asymptotic density). So in the end you are left with $\prod ( 1 - 1/p_n)$ fraction of the natural numbers; since the sum $\sum \frac{1}{p_n} = \infty$, this is the proportion zero. So we should expect the primes to have density zero.

Comment: Check out the [Riemann-zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) if you want something a bit more technical. It gives a pretty precise estimate of the distribution of primes, indirectly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article about the prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem):

> Roughly speaking, the prime number
>   theorem states that if a random number
>   nearby some large number N is
>   selected, the chance of it being prime
>   is about 1 / ln(N), where ln(N)
>   denotes the natural logarithm of N.
>   For example, near N = 10,000, about
>   one in nine numbers is prime, whereas
>   near N = 1,000,000,000, only one in
>   every 21 numbers is prime. In other
>   words, the average gap between prime
>   numbers near N is roughly ln(N).

Answer (score 5):

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a very intuitive visual representation of why the frequency of prime numbers goes down as you go further out on the number line.

Comment: This is really a less detailed version of Akhil's comment.

Comment: @BBischof Akhil's comment derives the answer to this question with mathematical rigor. My answer offers a link to a visual representation of the trend for the sake of gaining intuition. Its nice to have both the proof of the result and intuition about the result.

Comment: Agreed @Ami, it is a useful answer if not as rigorous.